# how to retrieve value from Application context in jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have to display the Values in drop down list based on popularty used one
that is

Doller
  Pound
  Euro
it should be populated based on which is the one is mostly used by user .

Example
if Euro is more number of user is used
it should be in first in the drop doum list

Comment: This is not a JSP/Servlet problem. This is more an algorithm problem (and you would have exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class). Have you thought out *something*? If so, where exactly are you stucking? How exactly are you collecting and storing the data about popularity?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could store the count of each variable (Dollar, Pound and Euro) in the session.

When a user selects Dollar, you'd do this in your receiving servlet:

```
Integer oldValue = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("Dollar");
request.getSession().setAttribute("Dollar", new Integer(oldValue.intValue()++)); // Add one
```

Simplest way to get the values from your JSP (before you display the dropdown) is like so:

```
Integer dollarCount = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("Dollar");
```

Then compare the values for dollarCount, poundCount, etc, to decide the order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but  this for single user, but i want application level

Comment: @user1000535 Then put it in the application context. The way the question was worded it sounds like you're doing it based on which is most used by an individual "user", not an aggregate of *all* the sites "users".